# Passing sums through set theoretic limits

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let's say I have a sequence of sets $\{S_{k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, where $S_{k} \subset \mathbb{N}$ for all $k$. Assume that this sequence has a limiting set $S$. Now consider a sequence of the form $\{x_{j}\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $x_{j} \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $j$. Does
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty}\sum_{j \in S_{k}}x_{j} = \sum_{j \in S}x_{j}
$$
always hold, assuming that the sum on the RHS is finite? If not, what conditions can be placed on the sequence $x_{j}$ so that this holds? It seems obvious that this result holds when $x_{j} > 0$ and $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}x_{j}$ converges but I was wondering if this holds more generally?

Comment: What does "this sequence has a limiting set $S$" mean? What's your definition of this? To be sure, there is a way to define what "limits" of sets means but I'm not sure what you're really using.

Comment: If by limiting set you mean that $S=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcap_{j\ge n}S_j=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}\bigcup_{j\ge n} S_j$, then it looks to me that you're just asking for the dominated convergence theorem for the counting measure (applied to te sequence of functions $f_k=x_\bullet\cdot\chi_{S_k}$ )

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio So the sequence $x_{j}$ combined with $S_{k}$ can be interpreted as a function $f_{k}$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ where $f_{k}(j)$ is equal to $x_{j}$ if $j \in S_{k}$ and zero otherwise. This sequence of functions will converge to pointwise to the function associated with $S$. Then we can employ the dominated convergence theorem as the integral will correspond to the summations in the claim. This is the logic right? So if the sum converges over $\mathbb{N}$ the result holds!

Comment: @MordeusMorgenstern I am using the definition given by Sassatelli in the comment above! Out of curiosity, how else may one typically specify a set-theoretic limit?

Comment: @NickBishop Yes, you understood my point. $\{x_j\}_{j\in\Bbb N}$ being $\ell^1$ is sufficient, and I would guess that if it isn't then there are a set $S$ and a sequence $S_k$ such that yada yada yada and the limits don't coincide. For instance, if $x_j>0$ and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j=\infty$, then consider $S_k=\{n\in\Bbb N\,:\, n\ge k\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to SassatelliGuilio, I now see that this problem can be solved via the Dominated Convergence Theorem. For each set $k$, we define the following function

$$
f_{k}(j) = 
\begin{cases} 
x_{j} & \text{if } j \in S_{k} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $f_{S}$ be similarly defined with the set $S$ in place of the set $S_{k}$. Then clearly $f_{k}$ converges pointwise to $f_{S}$. Moreover $f_{k} \leq g$ where $g$ is the function defined as $g(j) = \|x_{j}\|$. Under the counting measure, $g$ is integral as long as the sequence $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} x_{j}$ converges absolutely. In this case we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to conclude that
$$
\lim_{k} \sum_{j \in S_{k}}x_{j} = \lim_{k}\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}f_{k}(j) = \lim_{k}\int f_{k}\,d\mu = \int f_{S}\,d\mu = \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}f_{S}(x_{j}) = \sum_{j \in S}x_{j}.
$$

So as long as the series $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}x_{j}$ converges absolutely, then the claim holds.

I think you can also prove this without dominated convergence directly. Assume $\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}}x_{j}$ converges. Since $S_{k} \to S$, we know that for every $j \notin S$ there is a $k_{j}$ such that $j \notin S_{k}$ for all $k \geq k_{j}$. Similarly, for every $j \in S$ we know there is a $k_{j}$ such that $j \in S$ for all $k \geq k_{j}$. Moreover there is a $j_{0}$ such that $\left|\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}x_{j} - \sum_{j \leq j_{0}}x_{j}\right| \leq \epsilon$. Consider the set of indices $J$ defined as follows:
$$
J = \{j \: : \: j \leq j_{0}\}
$$

Clearly this set is finite. Similarly define the set $K$ as follows:
$$
K = \{k \: : \: \exists j \in J, k = k_{j}\}
$$

Again clearly the set $K$ is finite. Let $k^{\star} = \max_{k\in K}k$. Then we have $S_{k^{\star}}\cap\{x_{j} \: : \: j \in J\} \subseteq S$. Thus the only indices in $S_{k^{\star}}$ that are not in $S$ must staisfy $j > j_{0}$. But $\left|\sum_{j > j_{0}}x_{j}\right| \leq \epsilon$ so
$$
\left|\sum_{j \in S_{k}}x_{j} - \sum_{j \in S}x_{j}\right| \leq \epsilon
$$
Note that the same is true for all $k \geq k^{\star}$ and that $\epsilon$ can be chosen to be arbitrarily small since the sequence $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}x_{j}$ converges. Thus the proof is complete.